# how to append serialize with formdata in ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am tring to append **serilize** with **formdata**.It is not working.My **controller** as two viewmodel with httppostfilesbase as a parameter.i want to append both serilize collection with formdata and i went to send all data including file to controller.it is not working for me.can any one help on this please`

```
var fileData = new FormData();

    if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var fileUpload = $("#myFile").get(0);
                    var files = fileUpload.files;

                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);

                    }
                }

            }

        var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
        fileData.append('file',other_data );
       debugger
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Settlement")',
            data: fileData[0],
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.redirectTo) {

                } else {

                    $("#childcontent").html(result);
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `[0]`?

Comment: i have removed that [0].but it is not working for me.

Comment: That should fix the immediate problems in your JS code. If it still isn't working, check the console for errors after you send the request, and make sure the server side code is receiving the data correctly.

Comment: thanks for answer.i will check it

Comment: currently only file is posted in controller.not data.i.e serilize form data is not entering in to the controller.only file

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `fileData[0]`. Change `url` to `url: '/Settlement/Save',`

Also check the console for any errors and revert if you need more information

Can you try with this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Settlement/Save',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fileData,
    success: function(result) {
        if (result.redirectTo) {

        } else {

            $("#childcontent").html(result);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: contenttype giving error like this "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed,"

Comment: same code.due to content type is not going to controller.if i keep it false,it going to controller

Comment: In the updated answer the content type is false only @HarishSA

Comment: if i  change data into serilize() function.at that time data are posted in controller but file is not available